# Changes made to image surface aren't reflected when painting

Tags: c, image, gtk, cairo

I have a small code snippet which loads an image from a PNG file, then modifies the image data in memory by making a specific color transparent (setting alpha to 0 for that color). Here's the code itself:

```
static gboolean expose (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer userdata)
{
    int width, height, stride, x, y;
    cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(widget->window);
    cairo_surface_t* image;
    char* ptr;

    if (supports_alpha)
        cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); /* transparent */
    else
        cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); /* opaque white */

    cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    image = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png ("bg.png");
    width = cairo_image_surface_get_width (image);
    height = cairo_image_surface_get_height (image);
    stride = cairo_image_surface_get_stride (image);
    cairo_surface_flush (image);

    ptr = (unsigned char*)malloc (stride * height);
    memcpy (ptr, cairo_image_surface_get_data (image), stride * height);
    cairo_surface_destroy (image);

    image = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data (ptr, CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height, stride);
    cairo_surface_flush (image);

    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            char alpha = 0;
            unsigned int z = *((unsigned int*)&ptr [y * stride + x * 4]);

            if ((z & 0xffffff) == 0xffffff) {
                z = (z & ~0xff000000) | (alpha & 0xff000000);
                *((unsigned int*) &ptr [y * stride + x * 4]) = z;
                    }
        }
    }

    cairo_surface_mark_dirty (image);
    cairo_surface_write_to_png (image, "image.png");

    gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_OBJECT (window), width, height);
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_OBJECT (window), FALSE);

    cairo_set_source_surface (cr, image, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint_with_alpha (cr, 0.9);
    cairo_destroy (cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy (image);
    free (ptr);

    return FALSE;
}
```

When I dump the modified data to PNG, transparency is actually there. But when the same data is used as a source surface for painting, there's no transparency. What might be wrong?

Attachments:

- [image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5m9n.png) - modified data dumped to file for debugging purposes,
- [demo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxioc.png) - actual result
- bg.png - source image, is omitted due to stackoverflow restrictions, it's simply black rounded rectangle on the white background. Expected result is black translucent rectangle and completely transparent fields, not white, like these on the demo.png.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting alpha to 0 means that the color is completely transparent. Since cairo uses pre-multiplied alpha, you have to set the pixel to 0, since otherwise the color components could have higher values than the alpha channels. I think cairo chokes on those super-luminscent pixels.

So instead of this code:

`if ((z & 0xffffff) == 0xffffff) {
    z = (z & ~0xff000000) | (alpha & 0xff000000);
    *((unsigned int*) &ptr [y * stride + x * 4]) = z;
}`

You should try the following:

`if ((z & 0xffffff) == 0xffffff) {
    *((unsigned int*) &ptr [y * stride + x * 4]) = 0;
}`

And while we are at it:

- Doesn't `(z & 0xffffff) == 0xffffff` check if the green, blue and alpha channels are all at 100% and ignores the red channel? Are you sure that's really what you want? `z == 0xffffffff` would be opaque white.
- Instead of using `unsigned int`, it would be better if you used `uint32_t` for accessing the pixel data. Portability!
- Your code assumes that `cairo_image_surface_create_from_png()` always gives you an image surface with format ARGB32. I don't think that's necessarily always correct and e.g. RGB24 is possible as well.

I think I would do something like this:

`for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    uint32_t row = (uint32_t *) &ptr[y * stride];
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        uint32_t px = row[x];
        if (is_expected_color(px))
            row[x] = 0;
    }
}`

Comment: Actually, all three channels are taken in account - the mask 0xffffff corresponds to white color where red/green/blue channels are all set to 0xff (output png proves it right). Input alpha value doesn't matter. We have to force it to 0 for specific color. That's it. Other points: you're right, but it's rather a demo to show the problem, not live code yet :) Unfortunately, complete pixel reset didn't change much. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you happen to have some self-contained example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Sure. You can grab it [here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/46594e56). Unpack, run make in transparency/, then transp_demo bg.png. If you subsequently run transp_demo image.png, you'll get idea of what I need.

Comment: Uhm, I can't reproduce your problem. If change the code with what I said in my answer (no superlumniscent pixels, so assign 0 instead of z to the data array), everything works fine here...?! (Oh and cairo actually gives you a surface with format RGB24, so the alpha channel of the data is undefined and you are just lucky that this works at all...)

Comment: Oops. It really works! First time I tried your suggestions I simply replaced z = (z & ~0xff000000) | (alpha & 0xff000000); with z = 0. That didn't work. This time I took all your considerations into account and voila. I need better understanding how cairo works -_- Thank you very much for your help and sorry that I took your time.